# How can I get the raw XML response from a .NET generated SOAP client rather than serialized objects?

Tags: .net, xml, soap, svcutil.exe

I need to access the raw response XML from a .NET generated SOAP client (using `svcutil`). I believe that I can do this by intercepting it with a custom behaviour, but I don't really need the deserialized objects at all (and would rather not take the performance hit of creating them). Is there a way I can bypass the default serialization and access the raw response XML directly?

Comment: Perhaps you should look at implementing `IClientMessageFormatter`. In `DeserializeReply` method, you get SOAP object and you need to convert it into return value etc. Your implementation may create dummy objects or may throw an exception! Also, you will not get raw XML but a message object.